# s3 downloads not appearing in local folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Noob issue here- i'm using CLI to download an entire bucket of images from S3 (76 files of various image formats), however they do not seem to appear in my local folder after the code executes. After a few attempts, I then received the below error:

```
"download failed: s3://cpskitchenaidimages/KA/KA - 5KSM2APC_1.tif to ./KA - 5KSM2APC_1.tif [Errno 28] No space left on device"
```

Code run =

```
aws s3 sync s3://cpskitchenaidimages/KA .
```

My local directory = "C:\Users\Darren\Downloads\KA"

The bucket is publicly accessible via the below policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cpskitchenaidimages/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cpskitchenaidimages"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `No space left on device` error means that you do not have enough disk space to store the files. (Your disk is full.)

Comment: Interesting.....my drive shows >300GB of space though?